# IIS hosting performance

Tags: performance, iis

I just generated a question in my mind:
Will IIS service take much resources when nobody is using the service?

For example:
If I host Facebook website on my laptop and people in the work access my website, I am sure my laptop will stop working. However, if nobody use my Facebook, will IIS still takes much resouces because Facebook is a hugh application itself??

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. IIS will take resources only when it needs it.
Well, of course, if the application itself is written badly and does things like loading the whole database data into memory at application startup, this memory will be used, and as long as the application itself does not create say and endless loop with some sleeps in it, it won't take up a noticeable amount of CPU power.

So if the application is well designed and does not take a lot of memory for nothing, then your notebook will be as fast as you're used to it without the hosted application :)